# Rails 4 - HABTM model with 2nd level model design?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a design question.

I have two model objects; Event and EventSeries (types of series or championships that the event can be part of) where the Event can be belong to multiple EventSeries.

I am now looking to add a third object to the mix, Competitor that belongs to the Event and should be able to select associations to the EventSeries but only those that the Event is part of.

What is the best method for this type of design?

- HABTM between the Competitor and EventSeries and use the controller/view to limit the available entry values based on the Event model?
- HABTM between Event with custom keys (EventSeries) and the Competitors models? Not sure if possible
- Something else?

Cheers,

Derek.